# Can't navigate to other components in angular 7

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an angular project with 3 components namely:- Search,View,Insert, each component have their own routing-module and module.ts files.
However the issue is I am not able to navigate from Search to View or Insert by clicking on Sidebar Option. However if I create a button and use `this.router.navigateByUrl('/view');` then I am able to go to View Page.
Similarly in Insert Page also I am having same issue.
Project Structure:
[image: Project Hierarchy and Folder Structure]

Layout Routing File:-

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LayoutComponent } from './layout.component';
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: LayoutComponent,
        children: [
            { 
                path: '', 
                redirectTo: 'search', 
                pathMatch: 'prefix' 
            },
            {
                path: 'search', 
                loadChildren: './search/search.module#SearchModule'
            },
            {
                path: 'view', 
                loadChildren: './view/view.module#ViewModule'
            },
            {
                path: 'insert', 
                loadChildren: './insert/insert.module#InsertModule'
            },
        ]
    }
];
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LayoutRoutingModule { }
```

app.module.ts

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform- 
browser/animations';
import { LanguageTranslationModule } from './shared/modules/language- 
translation/language-translation.module';
import { AngularMaterialModule } from '../app/angular-material.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './shared';
import {MatFormFieldModule, MatSelectModule, MatInputModule,
MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material';
import { CustomHttpService } from '../app/shared/services/custom-           
http.service';
import { UserService } from './shared/services/user.service';
@NgModule({
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    LanguageTranslationModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    AngularMaterialModule
],
declarations: [AppComponent],
providers: [AuthGuard, CustomHttpService, UserService],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Sidebar.component.html

```
<nav class="sidebar" [ngClass]="{ sidebarPushRight: isActive, collapsed: 
collapsed }">
<div class="list-group">
<a routerLink="/search" [routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']" 
class="list-group-item">
  <i class="fa fa-fw fa-search"></i>&nbsp;
  <span>{{ 'Search' }}</span>
</a>
<a routerLink="/dashboard" [routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']" 
class="list-group-item">
  <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;
  <span>{{ 'Dashboard' }}</span>
</a>
<a routerLink="/dashboard" [routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']" 
class="list-group-item">
  <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;
  <span>{{ 'Insert' }}</span>
</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you show your app module?

Comment: Try to use this: this.router.navigate(['/view']);

Comment: @Sarkani where should I use ?

Comment: @JonasPraem I have added app.module file

Comment: Can you show a template where you have your `routerLink`'s?

Comment: Change this.router.navigateByUrl('/view'); to this.router.navigate(['/view']);

Comment: @JasonWhite In app.component.html I have only this much code <router-outlet></router-outlet>

Comment: In your app module you are importing `AppRoutingModule` and not your `LayoutRoutingModule`?

Comment: I guess what I mean is, can you show how you're trying to navigate in the sidebar options

Comment: @Sarkani but this on button click so it wont make difference by using a button i am able to navigate I want to be able to navigate if i write url or click on View or Insert on sidebar

Comment: @JasonWhite  I have added sidebar file

Comment: In which module you importing LayoutRoutingModule?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
<a [routerLink]="['/dashboard']"
 class="list-group-item">
 <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;
 <span>{{ 'Dashboard' }}</span>
</a>
```

for more information refer this https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink#description

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `[routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']` with `[routerDirection]="'root'"` in your Sidebar.component.html file

```
<a routerLink="/search" [routerDirection]="'root'" 
class="list-group-item">
  <i class="fa fa-fw fa-search"></i>&nbsp;
  <span>{{ 'Search' }}</span>
</a>
```